# Use VBA to change tab color based on locations

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

Good morning,

I am trying to figure out a code that I can use to change the tab color based on an vehicles location.

I.e. if Vehicle1 
is in locationA change tab color to white
If in locationB change tab color to red
If in locationC change tab color to blue
Etc etc

And I need to do this for multiple work sheets. Currently the location of the vehicle are on a cover sheet And each individual worksheet uses the cover sheet as the reference to display its location in cell F2 of its own worksheet.

Comment: Okay. So which part are you stuck on? Please [edit] your question to clarify - note that nobody on this site is expected to implement a solution for you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a "code-for-me" site. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and revise your question with your actual attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to do something along the lines of:

```
Public Sub Example()
    Select Case Worksheets(1).Range("B2").Value 'Location of Vehicle (LocationA, LocationB)
        Case "LocationA"
            Application.Worksheets(2).Tab.ColorIndex = 2 'White
        Case "LocationB"
            Application.Worksheets(2).Tab.ColorIndex = 3 'Red
    End Select
End Sub
```

`Worksheets(i).Tab.ColorIndex` sets the color of the referenced sheets tab. You could run this when the "cover sheet" `_change` event fires, for example.

If you struggle to implement this then give me a heads up and I'll be happy to help.